# Tex Add nodestyle

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

Is it possible to use different node styles with my "syntax" of defining the nodes (using `[. ]`).

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{german}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
    font=\small,
    edge from parent,
    level distance=1.75cm,
    every node/.style=
    {
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!25,
        rectangle,rounded corners,
        minimum height=8mm,
        draw=blue!75,
        thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=center,
        text depth = 0pt
        },
    edge from parent/.style=
        {
        draw=blue!50,
            thick
        }
}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
[.{$stmt : \grq\{\grq\ \{\ stmt\ \} * \grq\}\grq\ ;$}
            [.{$\grq\{\grq\ \{\ stmt\ \}*  \grq\}\grq\ ;$}
        [.{$\textbf{\grq\{\grq };$}
        ]
        [.{$\{\ stmt\ \}* ;$}
            [.{$stmt$}
            ]
            [.{$stmt$} 
            ]
            [.{$stmt$}
            ]  
        ]
        [.{$\textbf{\grq\}\grq };$}
        ]
            ]
    [.{$\grq\{\grq\ \{\ stmt\ \}  \grq\}\grq\ ;$}
            ]  
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At the moment there is just the `every node style`, but I would like to have two different types.

Sorry if my question is dumb, but this is my second day using any kind of TeX.

Comment: I get lots of warnings about `\grq` being invalid in maths mode.

Comment: You probably need to include "german". (\usepackage{german})

Comment: No. The problem is that the command cannot be used in maths mode. Including `german` ensures it is defined but it is not a maths mode macro, so you get lots of warnings.

Comment: Oh, okay. But it seems as if you solved this within your solution below.

Comment: Yes, using `\text{}` from `amsmath` allows the use of the text command while typesetting maths. It puts a bit of text sandwiched within the maths, so to speak. But you need something like this -`\text{}` seemed the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard `\node` command and apply a specific style to a given node. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,german]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  font=\small,
  edge from parent,
  level distance=1.75cm,
  every node/.style=
  {
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
  },
  odd node/.style={
    bottom color=red!25,
    draw=red!75
  },
  edge from parent/.style=
  {
    draw=blue!50,
    thick
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.{$stmt : \text{\grq}\{\text{\grq}\ \{\ stmt\ \} * \text{\grq}\}\text{\grq}\ ;$}
  [.{$\text{\grq}\{\text{\grq}\ \{\ stmt\ \}*  \text{\grq}\}\text{\grq}\ ;$}
    [.\node[odd node]{$\textbf{\text{\grq}\{\text{\grq} };$};
    ]
    [.{$\{\ stmt\ \}* ;$}
      [.{$stmt$}
      ]
      [.{$stmt$}
      ]
      [.{$stmt$}
      ]
    ]
    [.{$\textbf{\text{\grq}\}\text{\grq} };$}
    ]
  ]
  [.{$\text{\grq}\{\text{\grq}\ \{\ stmt\ \}  \text{\grq}\}\text{\grq}\ ;$}
  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: red node]

I've also made a couple of other changes to your code, using `\text{\grq}` since `\grq` is not usable in maths mode and using the `german` option for `babel` rather than calling `german` as a package, which I believe is deprecated.

It seems unlikely that you really want quotation marks which look like that. But, on the other hand, it isn't clear what you might want instead so hopefully just providing the `\text{}` will enable you to modify the code appropriately.

If you use `forest`, it is possible to apply styles to particular nodes rather more flexibly and concisely, but I'm not sure whether that can be done using `tikz-qtree` and you would need to use different syntax to use `forest`, which you stated you don't wish to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much. Really appreciate that there are guys like you spending there time on problems of others.

Comment: @Muffex Glad it helped but note that it is dangerous to make assumptions online ;). In any case, if my solution solves the problem, please consider accepting it when you are ready by clicking on the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the answer.